# get value from recordset protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

i am looking to extract the value from the following recordset object to compare it with a value of a web element using protractor. Please help

```
recordset: [ { '': 178 } ],
```

I converted it to a json string using stringify, unable to proceed after that

```
var a = JSON.stringify(count);
```

and the value becomes .`[ { '': 178 } ]`

```
it('tests db connection', function (done) {

ConnectDB().then(function _onSuccess(_returned){
    //console.log(_returned.recordset[0]);
    var count =_returned.recordset;
    console.log(count)
    browser.recordcount = count;

    done();
}).catch(function _onFailure(err){
    done.fail(err);
```

I tried to split the string using : but i am getting the value 178}] , can someone suggest a possible solution?

Comment: Why convert to string? You can just do `Object.values(recordset[0])[0]`

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear , the recordset returns a count from the database. It  does not have a key,   getting the followin message " Failed: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Could you syntax specific to my code,I am getting little confused if I am doing it the right way

Answer (score 0):

Lets say:

```
var a = JSON.stringify(count);
console.log(a);
[ { '': 178 } ]
```

Then you can extract 178 using this code:

```
var cout =x[0][''];
console.log(cout);
178
```